# Inserting HTML into an AngularJS ng-repeat table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to insert a form as a new row underneath a row generated by `ng-repeat`. I can successfully add a row to the data model using `.splice()` but I'm not able to render the HTML when it is inserted. I have researched methods to accomplish this and the ones that are mentioned the most frequently involve the `$watch` and `$compile` functions. The issue is that I do not have an original tag to insert into as this is a brand new row in the table.

Idea behind this: 
I have a table of data with many rows. The table represents data on "actions" that are for employees to accomplish. We are creating a web app that allows them to view their own actions and update them in the web page rather than updating a spreadsheet.

I was originally inserting a row dynamically with jQuery but as we are aware - it breaks the DOM. I'm trying to take the angular approach as this is an angular app, but I'm struggling with how to accomplish this.

The row that is inserted is a form for all the fields chosen and some extra ones not shown in the "view". Ideally, this would expand a row downwards when they click a button at the end of the row containing the action they are trying to edit. When they are done they can click a save button which removes/collapses the row and saves the changes to the model. This change is then sent back to the API to write the changes back to the database.

View of the Table:
[Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuRz1.jpg)

View of the Form:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUjbo.jpg)

Basically, I'd like to dynamically insert the form between rows shown in the table. I have to avoid **jQuery** and use **AngularJS** if possible.

Anyone have a neat trick to accomplish this?

Code (had to remove some stuff for privacy):
Pastebin: jf1mv9WG

Cheers,
Tux889

Comment: Any change you could put up your code so we have something to work off of?

Comment: *I was originally inserting a row dynamically with jQuery but as we are aware - it breaks the DOM* Inserting a row dynamically with jQuery shouldn't break the DOM.

Comment: Why not just generate the form within the ng-repeat and then hide or show it in response to the button?

Comment: @DrC Would that not impact performance of the page if you had a long list? Seems it would add a lot of extra HTML.

Comment: While it will get large, it will be easier.  Try it and see if it actually causes issues.   Browsers routinely handle insanely overbuilt DOMs so I suspect it will be fine.  Bigger issue might be the digest process.  I don't know its performance model though.

Comment: It went from loading in 1-2 seconds to taking about 10.. I agree this would be the simplest but I can't take that performance hit or my users will complain (they are very picky haha)

Comment: building off of what @DrC suggested, `ng-if` would only render the element if the condtion is true, vs `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, which render the rows regardless.  You could easily use `ng-if` to conditionally render the form from an `ng-include`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question (and assuming you are using angular 1x), maybe you can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to render two rows for every item; and in the second row put the form inside a `td[colspan=n]` (where `n` is the number of columns in your table). And make the two rows mutually exclusive, for example the first row can have `ng-if="!item.showForm"` and the second row can have `ng-if="item.showForm"`.

Take a look a this example that I prepared: https://jsfiddle.net/miguelerm/9pus3zoc/

Comment: I forgot mention that I use ng-if to prevent the form element in the DOM when it isn't necessary.

Comment: This is brilliant - I implemented the ideas into my code and it's exactly what I was looking to do! Thanks so much, I really appreciate the learnings!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [ngBindHtml directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

You can bind html to your table.